# WordPress-based ticketing systems?

Tags: wordpress, helpdesk

I have been asked to set up a ticketing/help desk system for a small nonprofit.  Our server runs Debian GNU/Linux.

Because we already have WordPress installed and plan to exploit it heavily going forward, I'm wondering whether there are any WP-based ticketing systems.  Obviously, it will simplify the admin's life to have less software installed on the server.

Thanks.

Comment: Turning wordpress into a ticketing system will do the opposite of simplify the admins life. Check out Helpspot. http://www.helpspot.com We use it for ticketing, runs on php/mysql. Fantastic and very affordable product with great support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While having less software installed will (marginally) reduce the workload of the Admin, trying to fit a square peg into a round hole the size of a pin (Turning a blogging product into a ticketing system) will completely destroy the benefits of ticketing systems.

If you are still looking open source for the ticketing systems, there is a whole [list](http://www.opensourcehelpdesklist.com/) of them.

If you can afford to pay, i've heard good things about [Cerberus Help-desk](http://www.cerberusweb.com/).

I can't recommend anything from experience right now mostly because i would not wish the two ticketing systems I've used over the past 4 years on my worst enemy.

Comment: +1 Square peg, round hole - sums it up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to follow Justin Tadlock's website. [He recently wrote](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress) about using custom post types in WP 3. One example he gave was a ticketing system ([image](http://justintadlock.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/issue-tracker.png)). He promises some more information on that in the future.

Given the changes coming in WP 3, WP will be able to be used for far more than just a blog.